# Чи звуки [ґ], [д͡з] і [д͡ж] вважаються офіційними звуками в Українській мові?

Tags: фонетика, приголосні

Коли я був дитиною, наша вчителька прийшла одного разу і каже — в українській мові додалися (сполучення) глухих та дзвінких звуків. Тепер у нас буде:

```
г - х
ґ - к
ч - дж
ц - дз
```

Я пам'ятаю, у нас поміняли букварі, та поставили `ґ` після `г`, а `дж` і `дз` — у кінці, перед апострофом.  Я ще пам'ятаю, що на `дж` починалось слово «джерело», а на `дз` — «дзюрчить».

Але після цього я більше не чув про ці «нові звуки».  Навіть на клавіатурі нема букви `ґ` — мені треба було її копіювати з charmap. Я тільки на одному календарі знайшов букву `ґ`.

Чи це ще є практика в Україні, асоціювати звуки таким чином, чи ні?

Answer (score 18):

Буква «Ґґ» присутня в сучасній українській абетці, після «Гг». В Windows її можна ввести на розширеній українській розкладці клавіатури або за допомоги **Ctrl+Alt+Г**, або **AltGr**(right Alt)**+Г**. На деяких клавіатурах ліворуч від клавіші з «Я» є додаткова фізична клавіша з буквою «Ґ».
До радянської реформи 1933, коли її прибрали з абетки, буква «ґ» вже існувала в українському правописі у своєму сучасному вигляді. Поновлено її було лише у правописі 1990. Проте сам звук [ɡ] зберігався весь цей час, незважаючи на відсутність графічного знаку. Наприклад, у орфоепічному словнику Погрібного (1983) цей звук транскрибується окремо знаком «ґ», і про нього надаються пояснення.

Твердий «дж» (d͡ʒ) та твердий і м'який «дз» (d͡z, d͡zʲ) — це питомі звуки української фонетики. Проте власних літер у сучасній абетці, на кшталт Џ і Ѕ, вони не мають, а на письмі передаються зазначеними сполученнями. Ці звуки можуть як існувати самостійно: б**дж**ола, кукуру**дз**а, так і виникати у вимові внаслідок уподібнення (асиміляції): ві**дч**иняти [d͡ʒt͡ʃ], ві**дс**туп [d͡zs].

Comment: Дякую що росказали як користуватися розширеною українською розкладкою.  А я то думав, чому вона називається росширенною...

Comment: Будь ласка! У ній також виправлена проблема з відсутністю апострофа. Тепер він разом зі значком гривні розташовується замість непотрібної «Ё».

Comment: Я б додав до відповіді, що ці звуки в українській мові дуже давно (принаймні з початку XX сторіччя, впевнений, що раніше). Навіть за радянських часі в орфоепічному словнику Погрібного в транскрипції використовувалося "ґ" (просто писалося "гава", а вимовлялося все одно "ґава"). За часів незалежності з дж/дз взагалі змін не було, а "ґ" просто додали як літеру до абетки.

Comment: А в мене є буква "ґ", але там де мав би бути апостроф чомусь вискакує клята "ё". Вона і росіянам вже не треба, а мені й поготів. Доводиться на англійську перемикати задля апострофа.

Comment: @Vlad Khersons'kyi то у вас мабуть, встановлена «стандартна» українська розкладка. Треба зайти в налаштування мов і для української вибрати «розширену» розкладку замість «стандартної».

Comment: @Alex, насправді вона називається розширеною не через Ґґ, а через апостроф (') і знак гривні (₴). Літера Ґґ була доступна як AltGr+Г вже в стандартній розкладці.

Answer (score 6):

Ці звуки завжди були в українській мові, букву **Ґ** можна побачити ще в [«Граматиці слов’янській»](http://litopys.org.ua/smotrgram/sm.htm) Мелетія Смотрицького, виданій в 1619 році, вона там прямо на [титульному аркуші](http://litopys.org.ua/smotrgram/sm02.htm) є, ориґінальна назва книги ­– «Граматики славенския правилное сѵнтаґма».

Аби позбутися проблем з введенням **Ґ** з клавіатури, раджу встановити [Українську розкладку клавіатури з символами Unicode](http://r2u.org.ua/wiki/keyboard/UkrainianUnicode), вона дозволяе без перемикання розкладки писати українською, російською й білоруською мовами, саме цією розкладкою я зараз пишу, **Ґ** там вводиться клавішею «\|» (біля клавіші «Enter») або Alt+г, апостроф – клавішею «`~» (це клавіша в верхньому лівому кутку клавіатури під клавішею «Esc»). Всі інструкції по встановленню й застосуванню цієї розкладки є там на її сторінці за посиланням, яке я навів вище.

Ще хотів би зазначити, що невірно думати, що «х» є глухим відповідником «г», як вам казала вчителька. Х [x] – це *задньоязиковий* приголосний, утворюється притисканням задньої частини спинки язика до м’якого піднебіння, а Г [ɦ] – це *фаринґальний* звук, при його вимові нічого нікуди не притискається, він вимовляється в гортані й є дзвінким відповідником англійського й німецького звука [h]. Дзвінкою парою до Х [x] є *задньоязиковий* дзвінкий приголосний звук [ɣ], який є основним звуком Г в білоруській мові та в південних діалектах та говорах російської. Багато хто вимовляє його й в українській замість [ɦ], та це є грубою орфоепічною помилкою, спричиненою, зокрема, й такими вчительками, як та, про яку ви розказували.

Comment: @VladKhersons'kyi, цікаво, що деякі словники, наприклад, 2-е видання «Практичного словника синонімів української мови» С. Караванського (причому не в розпізнаному варіанті, бо там такі нюанси губляться) пропонує писати саме через ґ з гачком.

Answer (score 6):

<sub>Перепрошую, неуважно прочитав запитання, відповідь була лише на частину. Доповнюю…</sub>

Так, звісно, **звуки [ґ], [д͡з] і [д͡ж] є в українській вимові**, і офіційно визнаються українською фонетикою³.

**Літера Ґ є в абетці та на клавіатурі**², хоча використовується вона нечасто.

«У нас поміняли букварі, та поставили […] *дж* і *дз* — у кінці, перед *апострофом*», як на мене, звучить дивно. По-перше, наскільки я знаю, **апостроф не вважається частиною української абетки**, бо хоч і використовується на письмі, але не вважається літерою (так само, як, наприклад, використовується на письмі, але не вважається літерою дефіс).

По-друге, **немає літери «дз»** і **немає літери «дж»** — те, що літери «д» і «з» при написанні поряд продукують один звук [д͡з], а літери «д» і «ж» при написанні поряд (найчастіше) один звук [д͡ж], не робить «дз» і «дж» новими літерами. Слід розрізняти *літери (букви)* та *звуки*: одна літера може продукувати декілька звуків (наприклад: «я» — [йа]), а декілька літер — один звук (наприклад: «нн» в слові «насіння» — довга м'яка [н':]). «Дз» — це *дві* літери, що створюють один звук (дзвінкий варіант [ц]), а не одна літера; так само щодо «дж».

Хоч я іноді й бачив «дз», «дж» і апостроф в онлайн-версіях *білоруської абетки* — але ніколи в українській (і, власне, не впевнений щодо правильності тієї білоруської). Бо абетка — це зазвичай список *літер*, а не звуків чи нелітерних орфограм (орфографічних знаків).

Приголосні звуки зараз асоціюють саме таким чином: [п]–[б], [т]–[д], **[х]–[г]**¹, **[к]–[ґ]**, [с]–[з], **[ц]–[д͡з]**, [ш]–[ж], **[ч]–[д͡ж]**<sub>, [т']–[д']</sub><sub>, [с']–[з']</sub><sub>, [ц']–[д͡з']</sub><sub>, [ч']–[д͡ж']</sub> і без пари [в], [й], [л], [м], [н], [р], [ф].

---

Примітки:

¹ Насправді ⟨х⟩–⟨г⟩ не уворюють точну пару глухий–дзвінкий, бо ⟨х⟩ — це <sub>МФА</sub>[[x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_velar_fricative)] (точною парою якого є <sub>МФА</sub>[[ɣ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_velar_fricative)]), а [г] — це найчастіше (хоч [є різні погляди](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ukrainian_phonology&oldid=757420361#Consonants)) <sub>МФА</sub>[[ɦ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_glottal_fricative)] (точною парою якого є <sub>МФА</sub>[[h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_glottal_fricative)]). Тим не менш [в рамках шкільної програми](http://zno.academia.in.ua/mod/book/view.php?id=1357) акустичною парою вважається саме ⟨х⟩–⟨г⟩. Мабуть, це визначаються тим, що ближчих відповідників в українській фонетиці немає, а також тим, яке місце вони займають в системі української фонетики.

² Хоча її розташування наразі різниться в [розкладках](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8) IBM PC-сумісної американської (101/104-клавішної) клавіатури для MS Windows та GNU/Linux: в MS Windows вона доступка як <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Г</kbd> (3-ій і 4-ий рівні англійської <kbd>U</kbd>), а в GNU/Linux — на місці англійської <kbd>\ <sup>|</sup></kbd>. На європейській (102/105-клавішній) же IBM PC-сумісній клавіатурі, окрім вищезазначених місць, вона присутня у вигляді окремої клавіші біля лівого <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

³ Також існує версія, що звуки ⟨д͡з⟩ і ⟨д͡ж⟩ насправді не вкоренилися глибоко в українській фонетичній системі.

> Це пояснюєтся в тому числі особливостями чергування.
>
> Наприклад, є ряд
>     ⟨х⟩ → ⟨с⟩ → ⟨ш⟩   (му**х**а → му**с**і → му**ш**ка);
>     в нього є дзвінкий аналог
>     ⟨г⟩ → ⟨з⟩ → ⟨ж⟩   (но**г**а → но**з**і → ні**ж**ка)
>     — що виглядає повністю логічним, бо дзвінкими парами для ⟨х⟩, ⟨с⟩ і ⟨ш⟩ є саме ⟨г⟩, ⟨з⟩ і ⟨ж⟩.
>
> Також є ряд
>     ⟨к⟩ → ⟨т͡с⟩ → ⟨т͡ш⟩   (ону**к**а → ону**ц**і → ону**ч**ка);
>     за логікою його дзвінким аналогом мав би бути
>     ⟨ґ⟩ → ⟨д͡з⟩ → ⟨д͡ж⟩   (дзи**ґ**а → дзи**дз**і → дзи**дж**ка)
>     — але на практиці нормою вважається
>     ⟨ґ⟩ → ⟨  з⟩ → ⟨  ж⟩:   (дзи**ґ**а → дзи**з**і → дзи**ж**ка).
>
> Чергування ⟨ґ⟩→⟨д͡з⟩→⟨д͡ж⟩ (дзиґа→дзидзі→дзиджка) вживається в деяких західних діалектах. Але лише в деяких, поширенішим і літературною нормою є ⟨ґ⟩→⟨з⟩→⟨ж⟩ (дзиґа→дзизі→дзижка).
>
> Професор Ю. Шевельов в своїй праці «A Historical Phonology of the Ukrainian Language» стверджує: «незважаючи на такі сприятливі передумови, звук ⟨д͡з⟩ в українській мові глибоко не закоренився […] У системі української мови не з’явилося жодного звукового закону, який би сприяв його реґулярному ширенню. Цей звук уживався радше як емфатичний засіб (саме через це він так часто обіймає позицію на початку слова) в афективних та звуконаслідувальних словах […] Проте жодне з цих явищ так і не набуло рис системності. Таким чином, звук уживається в небагатьох словах за традицією, в інших — як емфатичний елемент (а отже — факультативний), охопивши в обох випадках лише невеличку частину лексики. На сьогодні звук ⟨д͡з⟩ найбільше поширений у південно-західному наріччі (Карпати, Придунав’я), але оскільки навіть у цих реґіонах, як здається, бракує мінімальних пар, то й статус його непевний. Із просуванням на схід кількість слів із ⟨д͡з⟩ дедалі меншає, а вжиток його стає факультативним. […] Звісно, в цьому процесі свою роль міг відіграти також вплив російської мови, яка не має ⟨д͡з⟩. Початково постання звука в українській мові вписувалося в аналогічний процес, що відбувався на великій території, охопивши Північну Грецію, Македонію, частину Болгарії, частину Румунії, Україну та частину Словаччини. Проте з XVIII ст. ці контакти увірвалися — хоч під яким оглядом їх брати» (правопис перекладу збережено, але позначення звуку змінене на таке, що використовується в усій відповіді).
>
> [Докладніше](http://ua-etymology.livejournal.com/252050.html).

А не можна це вважати 100%-ю істиною, бо думки різних людей не збігаються. <sub>Мені от особисто взагалі здається, що це звук ⟨ґ⟩ остаточно не вкоренився в українській мові, тому в словах з ⟨ґ⟩ чергування відбувається по схемі для ⟨г⟩ — а звуки ⟨д͡з⟩ і ⟨д͡ж⟩ якраз вкоренилися, — але я не спеціаліст і моя думка нічим не підкріплюється.</sub>

Comment: Важко судити. Я носій літературної і східної вимови. Для мене «ґ» — цілком зрозуміла але необов'язкова сутність. Я і російською «гекаю». У той час як дж-дз досить звичні.

Comment: @Ukurainajin, ну, якщо я правільно зрозумів: Ви прекрасно розумієте між ними різницю, але не заморочуєтесь. Типу, якщо хтось Вам скаже «його за вбивство посадили за грати», Ви, мабуть, і не помітите помилку — якщо спеціально не звертатимете увагу. Тобто різницю Ви відчуваєте, але підсвідомо вважаєте несуттєвою. Тому й чергуєте [ґ] за схемою для [г]: дзиґа—дзизі—дзижка.

Comment: @Ukurainajin, a представник якогось іншого діалекту, може, навпаки («як це: заграти посадили? на чому заграти, на музичному інструменті? а до чого тут вбивство, хіба грати — то покарання?»). Тобто в його підсвідомості [г] і [ґ] — то зовсім різні звуки. Невзаємозамінні (як «р» і «ц», наприклад). То він, мабуть, і чергує за окремими схемами (книга–книзі–книжка — дзиґа–дзидзі–дзиджка).

Comment: @Ukurainajin, але це лише моя теорія, можу й помилятися. Он професор Ю. Шевельов вважає навпаки: що [ґ] якраз вкоренилася, а [д͡з] і [д͡ж] не вкоренилися.

Comment: Моя покійна бабуся все життя говорила виключно українською, центральноукраїнським діалектом (комарь, сахарь), була фельдшером, тобто не філологом, та все ж чітко розрізняла «г» та «ґ», завжди казала «ґава», «аґрус», «ґанок», тощо, її українська була краща, ніж у всіх вчителів української, яких я зустрічав за все своє життя. Я українською навчився говорити в неї, і для мене різниця між «г» та «ґ» настільки ж значуща, як між «г» та «д». Ваші арґументи слабкі. Не забувайте, «ґ» – це пізній запозичений звук, пізніший навіть від «ф», зовсім не дивно, що він чергується не так, як очікувалося б.

Comment: @YellowSky, але ж в деяких діалектах воно чергується так, як очікується. Тобто фактично теорія про таке чергування підтверджується — але чомусь лише для найзахідніших діалектів, ось що дивно. Добре, а що Ви думаєте про [д͡з]/[д͡ж]?

Comment: Діалекти на те й діалекти, що в кожному все по-своєму, є українські діалекти, в яких навіть дифтонґи є, у нас тут діалектний континуум від Волги до Ельби («Ўобйо» лужицькими), якщо що. Про [д͡з]/[д͡ж] я нічого не думаю, як і про [п]/[б], звуки як звуки. Чи ви хочете сказати, що «лапландський» та «приїжджай» вимовляється без цих звуків? Єдине, що я хочу відмітити, так це те, що [х] _не є_ глухим відповідником [г], дивіться мою відповідь на це запитання.

Comment: Те, що український [г] фаринґальний, не може бути жодного сумніву, це написано в усіх книжках, навіть радянських, хіба що іноді пишуть не «фаринґальний», а «гортанний», та це справи не міняє, він точно не задньоязиковий, як [x]. Те, що вони пом’якшуються в схожі ряди з-с ж-ш, які творять пари дзвінкий-глухий, нічого не говорить про співвідношення самих г-х. Щодо Ґ я вже все написав, не свідомо, не підсвідомо воно в мене з Г не асоціюється й не змішується. Ви мали справу з чеською або словацькою? От там все, як і в нас, є рідне h (г) і є запозичене g (ґ) в іноземних словах, все просто.

Answer (score 1):

> Чи звуки [ґ], [д͡з] і [д͡ж] вважаються офіційними звуками в Українській мові?

Не дуже розумію, що тут намагали подати дописи, але так, **вважаються**, ось [передмова чинного правопису](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil0.htm), де все *коротко* пояснено:

> УКРАЇНСЬКИЙ АЛФАВІТ
>
> ```
> А а,   Б б,   В в,   Г г,   Ґ ґ,   Д д,         Е е,   Є є,  
> Ж ж,   З з,   И и,   І і,   Ї ї,   Й й,         К к,   Л л,  
> М м,   Н н,   О о,   П п,   Р р,   С с,         Т т,   У у,  
> Ф ф,   Х х,   Ц ц,   Ч ч,   Ш ш,   Щ щ   Ь ь,   Ю ю,   Я я
> ```
>
> **Примітка.** Апостроф (’) в алфавіт не входить і на розміщення слів у словнику не впливає; напр.: бур’ян, буряний стоятимуть поруч.
>
> Сполучення літер ***дж*** і ***дз*** (для позначення зімкнено-щілинних звуків [дж̃], [дз̃]) не входять в алфавіт; отже, такі слова, як *джерело*, *дзвін*, стоятимуть у словнику під літерою *д*.

Як бачно, є буква *ґ* та двознаки *дж* та *дз* з відповідними звуками.

---

> Чи це ще є практика в Україні, асоціювати звуки таким чином, чи ні?

Деякою мірою так, але я радше сказав б що ні. Передусім це повʼязано з досі промосвосковським правописом та мовознавчим інстітутом. Деякі проблеми правопису можна почитати [тут](/q/2627/) (я далеко не завершив, але періодично доповнюватиму при настрою) або відзнайти [дещо](/search?q=%D2%91) пошуком. Питання постають до правопису та інституту і нині, он наприклад вибіркова цітата з вчорашньої статті:

> [Гірка доля українського правопису, Юрій Винничук](//zbruc.eu/node/81889)
>
> Українська національна комісія з питань правопису була заснована ще в 1994 році, куди входило понад тридцять мовознавців та літераторів, серед яких було п’ятеро з-за кордону, зокрема Юрій Шевельов. Але робочою групою керували тодішній директор Інституту української мови професор Олександр Тараненко та завідувачка відділу того ж інституту Світлана Єрмоленко, які нізащо не хотіли поступатися «визначними мовними завоюваннями» московського режиму. Тобто нищення української мови, яке відбулося в 1933, 1946 і 1960 роках, вони вважали здобутками.
>
> У підсумку комісія не дійшла згоди. Щойно коли інститут очолив академік Василь Німчук, вдалося в 1999 році підготувати «Проєкт найновішої редакції "Українського правопису"». Його також опублікувала преса. І почалося те, що ми давно вже фіксуємо на широких просторах інтернету: кількість «знавців мови» з конгеніяльним арґументом «у нас так не кажуть» зашкалила. Вереск та істерика трудящих мас звично перекрикували голоси науковців та письменників. Думку трудящих гаряче підтримали відомі москвофіли Віталій Русанівський та Петро Толочко разом із російськомовною пресою.
>
> …